# How can I change the reflux listenTo mixin based on a prop in a react.js component

Tags: reactjs, jsx, refluxjs

Can anyone help with this...

I have this list component and I want to be able to switch different data stores (defined in props)

```
mixins:[Reflux.listenTo(RecentPupilsStore, 'onChange')],
```

But I want to do this -

```
mixins:[Reflux.listenTo(this.props.store, 'onChange')],
```

But props don't appear to be available in the mixin. I also tried to transfer it to a function:

```
mixins:[Reflux.listenTo(this.setStore(this.props.store), 'onChange')],
setStore: function(store){
    if(store == 'RecentPupilsStore') { return RecentPupilsStore; }
},
```

Any help appreciated. pretty new ot react but trying to make it as reusable as possible!

EG: I want to include the component like this:

```
<FilterList data="pupils" />
<FilterList data="groups" />
```

etc - and these would look at these stores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would pass on using the mixin and just listen to both stores and map your data accordingly.

```js
componentDidMount = () => {
    // console.log('AppCtrl componentDidMount');
    this.unsubscribeApp = AppStore.listen(this.appStoreDidChange);
    this.unsubscribeGS = GenusSpeciesStore.listen(this.gsStoreDidChange);
};
componentWillUnmount = () => {
    this.unsubscribeApp();
    this.unsubscribeGS();
};
appStoreDidChange = () => {
    this.setState(getAppState());
};
gsStoreDidChange = () => {
    this.setState(getGsState());
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @J Mark Stevens - Sorry, probably my explanation but I only want to watch one of the stores at a time - this will only change across pages. So Pupils page will be fed /pupils data and Groups page will be fed /groups data. It's just the component that will be reusable. I want to initialise the component like: `<List data="pupils" />` and this woul watch the pupil store.

Comment: Apologies @J. Mark Stevens I misread your code. I see what you're doing now - I have now followed this and this https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs#user-content-react-component-example and seen that the listen action can go in componentDidMount() - Thanks marking as correct :)

Answer (score 1):

I won't say that this is the best solution, but it gives an answer to your question on how to use props to define the name of the store to listen to.

You don't need to define the store and method where you apply the Mixin. You can make use of the more general 'Reflux.ListenerMixin' and combine that with the registration of the listener in 'ComponentDidMount'.

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    mixins: [Reflux.ListenerMixin],
    // Lifecycle events
    componentDidMount: function() {
        var theStore = defineTheStore(this.props.data);
        this.listenTo(theStore, this.onChange);
    },
    render: function() {
        return(
            <div >
                ....
            </div>
        );
    },
    onChange: function() {

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Björn, that is similar to how I resolved it in the end :) Thanks for the reply.